# I want to display data last 7 days with date wise in chartjs?

Tags: plugins, wp-query, javascript

Hello I am building simple plugin and i want to make a chart, I have used chartjs. Its displaying static data, I want label datewise. Example today 13-12-2022, So the lebel should start from 06-12-2022. Bellow my code that i am trying but not getting all dates into label in chartjs.

```
$posts             = get_posts( [ 'post_type' => 'docs', 'date_query' => array( array( 'after' => '1 week ago', 'inclusive' => true))] );
$docs_num          = count( $posts );

$labels = [];
$dataCount = [];
foreach ( $posts as $item ) {
    $labels[] =  date('d M, Y', strtotime($item->post_date));
    $dataCount[] =  get_post_meta( $item->ID, 'post_views_count', false );
}
```

Here is my chartjs code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ['07 Dec 2022', '08 Dec 2022', '09 Dec 2022', '10 Dec 2022', '11 Dec 2022', '12 Dec 2022', '13 Dec 2022'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
            },
            {
                label: 'My Second dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 43, 122)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 45, 122)',
                data: [0, 20, 3, 4, 30, 40, 41]
            }
        ]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate the labels for your chart with the dates for the last 7 days (including the current day), you can use the `Date` object in JavaScript to generate the dates. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to do that:

```
    // Generate the labels for the chart
var labels = [];
var today = new Date();
for ( var i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) {
    // Generate the date for each label by subtracting the number of days from the current date
    var date = new Date( today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - i );
    labels.push( date.toDateString() );
}

// Use the generated labels in the chart
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: labels, // Use the generated labels here
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
            },
            {
                label: 'My Second dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 43, 122)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 45, 122)',
                data: [0, 20, 3, 4, 30, 40, 41]
            }
        ]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

This code will generate an array of labels with the dates for the last 7 days (including the current day) in the format `dayOfWeek month dayOfMonth year`, and use that array as the labels for the chart.

Note: The `Date` object in JavaScript uses a zero-based index for months (0 for January, 1 for February, etc.), so make sure to subtract 1 from the month when generating the dates.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is working nice, But i want data with date wise, Can you check my php code. I want to show data with datewise. Example if today is 13-12-2022, I want to show total views from today to last 7 days. If you take a look my php code i think you can understand.

Comment: Please checkout this screenshoot https://prnt.sc/bkKtQxKYwTcU

Comment: I want like this sir:
column1     column2
02/25/2020      5
02/24/2020      0
02/23/2020      6
02/22/2020      2
02/21/2020      1
02/20/2020      0
02/19/2020      2

Comment: Sir, did you get chance to look on it?

Answer (score 0):

To display the data date-wise in the chart, you can use the `Date` object in JavaScript to iterate through the dates starting from 1 week ago and ending with today's date, and store the data for each date in an object. You can then convert each date to the desired format and use it as the key for the data in the object.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
// Get today's date and the date 1 week ago
    var today = new Date();
    var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - 7);
    
    // Create an object to store the data for each date
    var data = {};

// Loop through the dates starting from 1 week ago and ending with today's date
for (var d = oneWeekAgo; d <= today; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    // Convert the date to the desired format
    var date = d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {month: 'short', day: 'numeric'});

    // Get the post views count for the current date from the $posts array
    var views = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < $posts.length; i++) {
        if (date == $posts[i].post_date) {
            views = get_post_meta($posts[i].ID, 'post_views_count', false);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Store the views count for the current date in the data object
    data[date] = views;
}

// Update the chart's data with the new data
chart.data.datasets[0].data = data;
```

This code will generate an object with the data for each date in the format `'M/D'`, such as `'Dec/7'`, `'Dec/8'`, etc. for the past 7 days. You can then use this object to update the `data` for your chart and it should display the correct data for the past week.

Comment: You're awesome sir, but i got error $posts isnt defind. And one things sir i want to use like this way: <?php echo json_encode($label); ?>, and for data <?php echo json_encode($dataCount); ?>

If view value null date value will display 0.